# Prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^n i/2^i = 2 - (n+2)/2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me with this question please?

Prove that for all  $n\in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i} = 2 - \frac{n+2}{2^n}$$

Comment: How is this linear-algebra ?

Comment: I don't know. It's in my course that I'm taking and it's linear algebra...

Comment: @Belgi, I think this is the most misplaced tag on MSE. They probably think of "linear" as something like "plain" in "plain English".

Comment: what section would this go under then?

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following function:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x^i=x\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} 
$$
If you differentiate $f$ w.r.t. $x$:
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}=(x\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1})'
$$
Then it is enough to calculate $xf'(x)$ for $x=0.5$.

Comment: What does this mean to my question?

Comment: You put $x=\frac{1}{2}$ in the above equation and then you get your sum. It is better to do the calculation yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Series.2C_sum_to_n_terms),

here $a=d=1, r=\frac12$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac i{2^i}=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot \frac1{2^{i-1}} =\frac12\cdot\frac{1-[1+n-1]\frac1{2^n}}{1-\frac12}+\frac12\cdot\frac{\frac12\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^2}$$

$$=1-\frac n{2^n}+1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}=2-\frac n{2^n}-\frac 2{2^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ 
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i} =  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i+1}{2^{i+1}}
=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{i}{2^i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^i})
$$

$$
=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{2^i} -\frac{n}{2^n}+\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}{\frac{1}{2}})
$$

$$
 \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i} = -\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}+1-\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i}=-\frac{n}{2^n}+2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}
$$
$$
=-\frac{n+2}{2^n}+1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_i = \dfrac{i}{2^i}$ and remark that $u_{i+2}-u_{i+1} + \dfrac{u_i}{4} = 0$ for all $i \geq 1$. Now, it is easy because
$$
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^n u_i = \sum_{i=1}^n(u_{i+1}-u_{i+2}) = u_2 - u_{n+2}.
$$