# How to find the sum of series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, self-learning

I am learning about series of numbers at the moment. In the book there is an exercise in which I need to find the sum of :
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^i}$$
I know it is equal to $2$. But how do I get to that result?
Are there any general ways of finding the sums of series? In the books I am using, there is a lot about series, their convergence etc. but almost no examples.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Series.2C_sum_to_n_terms and http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series  or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: [Prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^n i/2^i = 2 - (n+2)/2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512065/prove-that-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-sum-i-1n-i-2i-2-n2-2n)

Comment: See [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: [Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2/337952#337952)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$S := \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}.$$

Since all of its elements are positive and the series is absolutely convergent, we can do the following:

\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{2^k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k-1}{2^{k-1}} + 1 = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k-1}{2^{k-1}} + 1 = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k} + 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}S + 1,
\end{align*}

so $S = 2$.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^i}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}+\sum_{i=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}+\dots=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^j}=1\cdot 2$$.

But, of course, you need to say something about absolute convergence to manipulate the series in such a way.

Comment: Perhaps you should use two different indices in your last expression.

Comment: They are "independent" but I agree, that looks better and less confusing. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Then we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$. Can you see a derivative under a sum?